# Capture exception for all class methods with class decorator don't work for init method

Tags: exception, python-decorators, python-class

I want to capture all the methods of `Myclass`(and give them a new exception type)
I created a class decorator to implement this but the exception handling doesn't cover the `__init__`

How can I fix this? or other way to implemetn this feature?
Thanks!

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    pass

def add_exception_handling(cls):
    class DecoratedClass(cls):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
            if callable(attr):
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    try:
                        return attr(*args, **kwargs)
                    except Exception as e:
                        raise CustomError(e)
                return wrapper
            else:
                return attr
    return DecoratedClass

@add_exception_handling
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        1 / 0
    def method1(self):
        1 + '1'
    def method2(self):
        a
```

what I expected is:
when execute

```
myclass = MyClass()
```

the target result is:
CustomError: division by zero

actually I got:
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero